# encrypting data using blowfish under flash

Tags: flash, encryption, blowfish

how can i encrypt data in flash? is there a toolkit or class or something that can help me do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**as3crypto**](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about as3corelib which offers some decent implementations of common encryption schemes.

http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/secure_swf_apps_12.html) at the Adobe Developer Connection?  Other than follow the advice in the article, I don't necessarily see why you couldn't just use something like HTTPS (although, admittedly, my knowledge of Flash is limited).